# Count Subcategory and main category base item

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find out the sum of following sql.

```
SELECT SUM('amount') AS Amount,
       CASE amount WHEN(IS_SUB=1) THEN
                  (SELECT SUM(amount) AS amo
                   FROM product
                   WHERE id=Pid) + SUM('amount')
           ELSE SUM('amount')
       END AS totalamount
FROM product
ORDER BY totalamount DESC
```

Please find dummy data below.

```
id   amount  is_sub  pid
12    200     1       14
13    300     0       null
14    400     0       null
15    500     1       14
```

Expected Result :

```
id   amount totelamount  is_sub  pid
12    200      200        1       14
13    300      300        0       null
14    400      900        0       null
15    500      500        1       14
```

As you can see 12 and 15 have pid=14. So amount of 12 and 15 will be added to its parent 14

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what's the expected result (with that sample data)?

Comment: your sum don't have a group by ,what is your expect output?

Comment: Watch out the update . plz

Comment: amount of `12` and `15` is `200` and `500`. Adding it gives `700`. Adding `700` to `400` gives `1100`. Why should you get `900`?

Comment: Yup My mistake its 1100

Comment: @codeBloger - Cool. Please check the answer below and accept it if it works for you, so the question can be closed. Else let us know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the expected output is wrong as I explained in comment. For `14` , `sumtotal` should be `1100`.

This is how you can get it.

```
SELECT m.id,
       m.amount,
       CASE
           WHEN n.pid IS NULL THEN m.amount
           ELSE n.sum_amount+m.amount
       END AS total_amount,
       m.is_sub,
       m.pid
FROM product m
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT sum(p.amount) AS sum_amount,
                           p.pid
   FROM product p
   INNER JOIN product c ON p.pid=c.id
   GROUP BY p.pid
   ) n 
   ON m.id=n.pid
ORDER BY m.id
```

**Explanation**

Inner table `n` will give this output.

```
+------------+-----+
| SUM_AMOUNT | PID |
+------------+-----+
|        700 |  14 |
+------------+-----+
```

You can join it with `product` table to get below output.

```
+-----+---------+---------------+---------+-----+
| ID  | AMOUNT  | TOTAL_AMOUNT  | IS_SUB  | PID |
+-----+---------+---------------+---------+-----+
|  12 |     200 |           200 |       1 |  14 |
|  13 |     300 |           300 |       0 |     |
|  14 |     400 |          1100 |       0 |     |
|  15 |     500 |           500 |       1 |  14 |
+-----+---------+---------------+---------+-----+
```